# JDeveloper 12c getting navigation error after migration my Apps from JDeveloper 11.1.2.4

Tags: java, oracle11g, jdeveloper, oracle12c, oracle-adf-mobile

I have migrated my application from JDeveloper 11.1.2.4 to JDeveloper 12c(12.1.3.0). My demo application cleaned and compiled successfully. But when i am running my application, i am not able to navigate from one amx page to another amx page from code.

For both android and iOS devices, i am not able to navigate and for navigation i have used this line.

```
AdfmfContainerUtilities.invokeContainerJavaScriptFunction(AdfmfJavaUtilities.getFeatureName(), "adf.mf.api.amx.doNavigation", new Object[] { action });
```

In android devices, I am not getting an alert box but in iOS devices I am getting an error as

[image]

and also Tabbar images are scaled up in iOS devices but working fine in Android devices.

Any idea regarding this.

Thanks,
Siddharth

Comment: I assume you are migrating from ADF Mobile (ADFMF) to Mobile Application Framework (MAF)?

Comment: yes i have migrated from ADF mobile to MAF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first parameter for `invokeContainerJavaScriptFunction` is fueature id not feature name so all you have to do is to write your code as below.

```
 AdfmfContainerUtilities.invokeContainerJavaScriptFunction(AdfmfJavaUtilities.getFeatureId(), "adf.mf.api.amx.doNavigation", new Object[] { action });
```